# Unable to display all the buttons in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-view, android-button, android-tablelayout

I am generating buttons onto the screen programatically
This is my code

```
       TableLayout MainLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    MainLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //MainLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);

    for ( int i =0 ; i < gridSize ; i++){
        rowArr[i] = new TableRow(this);
        for(int j = 0; j < gridSize ; j++){

            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(Integer.toString(i)+","+Integer.toString(j));
            button.setTextSize(150/gridSize);
            button.setMaxHeight(450/gridSize);
            button.setMaxWidth(600/gridSize);
            rowArr[i].addView(button);

        }
        MainLayout.addView(rowArr[i]);
    }
```

---

[image]

By the seeing the image you can an entire column of buttons are missing.

Only after setting my gridSize to 6 or more does this problem occur.

Comment: Did you log our calculated width and the real width of the buttons? Sounds like the width is higher than it should be.

Comment: no i did not. I dont know how to use Log

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Use Log like this: Log.w("WIDGET","Enable is called");

Comment: gridSize is a constant. It is 6

Comment: Where did you get this gridSize? I can't find it in your code posted above...

Comment: I had declared it as a constant .I didn't include that declaration here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to see the 6th row on my emulator.I guess the phone width was the issue